# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle Error Summary

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using the Symfony2 FOSUserBundle and on the registration page, it puts inline errors beside the form elements that are in error, but I'd like to also display those errors in a summary at the top of the screen. Is there an error collection returned to the view that I'm not finding? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you check the default layout in user login page [github link](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig) you'll find a variable called error.
Which was set in the login controller [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L20)
So I'm assuming you could move this `error` variable to where ever you want in your template.

Hope this is what you were asking for.

Comment: Yeah, that works well on the login action/template, but the register action doesn't seem to offer the same thing.

Comment: You can set your own error variable in the controller according to what type of error it is, I'd suggest overriding the controller/view if you need a lot of customization, I don't remember how exactly but you can check this video
http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/fosuserbundle-ftw

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the registration template (these are two files ) in your userbundle and then take a look here

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

To see how to show every single one of your error-messages in your template.

This is the quickest way. You can also customize form appearance globally.

Comment: Ended up using some of the strategies from this page, but the FOS register action does not make this easy. I had to render each error individually at the top of the template as it wouldn't loop through any collection that I could find.